# Why is the predicted variable always biased towards center?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, prediction, bias

I am working on a prediction task where the output variable is a continuous unbounded variable. The original variable is a scale on 1-10. However, I did not bound the range on the output variable. Below is the frequency distribution for the original variable.

```
0     1098
1      622
2      468
3      321
4      185
5      509
6      225
7      355
8      429
9      338
10    1508
```

I have discretized the variable on the scale 1-3. Now below is how it looks.

```
1    2509
2    1274
3    2275
```

Surprisingly, the predicted variable follows the below frequency distribution. I have tried regression forest, XGBoost, MLP and they all show the same trend.

```
0.0      1
1.0    162
2.0    303
3.0    138
4.0      2
```

Besides the fact that the model did not learn much, the output is always biased towards the center whereas the original output variable has exactly the opposite frequency distribution. I was wondering if I am missing something obvious behind this specific trend. There are 150 predictor variables and a lot of those are one-hot encoded. I have tried the original set of variables and the reduced dimension by an autoencoder. Although the performance slightly improved after autoencoder which is 30% accuracy, the trend on the output remains the same for all the algorithms and original and various projected input space. Could anyone shed some light on this behavior? Below is the confusion metric if that is of any help.

```
Predicted   0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 All
Actual                      
1.0 1   67  112 50  0   230
2.0 0   29  72  31  0   132
3.0 0   66  119 57  2   244
All 1   162 303 138 2   606
```

Comment: Maybe your predictors are not uniquely associated to either side of the scale, i.e. many predictor values have both high and low output values, hence the prediction is averaged for most of the time. If this is the case then those predictors are maybe useless (and noise) for prediction, but as always, it depends on the case. I've done prediction of rating once and it ends up exactly like this because no features were distinctive enough to indicate high/low rating.